# Php doesn't work

Tags: apache2, php

I have on my webserver apache2 and php:

[image]

But if I write this code on my website:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I don't get the output you should get. The site just displays this :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Any solution?

Comment: For some reason the code doesnt shot up, its this : <?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: Check about `short_open_tag` in `/etc/php/x.x/apache2/php.ini` :)

Answer (score 2):

**PHP 5**

To verify that the php module is loaded, type:

```
a2query -m php5
```

if not enabled, then load with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**PHP 7.0**

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Verify:

```
a2query -m php7.0
```

Load:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```